# Real-time stock data/15 mins quotes for US stock exchanges?

Tags: programming, market-data

I am trying to figure of if there are free sources or inexpensive sources to get this type of data.
I see sites using BATS data, but BATS seems to have been bought out by CBOE and doesn't seem to have a free api anymore?

What about 15 min delayed quotes? Are there any free resources? I am assuming it's really expensive to get this sort of data from the exchange's official API?